# All columns in SQLite are text to save conversion

Tags: android, sqlite

I use sql lite for my android application. I want to know if what I am doing is correct. I found that typically a suer would enter a value in an editview, store it in db, and late display it.
Even if this value is a number, you will end up receiving it as String from GUI and displaying it as String.

Therefore, to avoid so many conversion from string to integer and back, I decided to have all my columns in the db of type TEXT.

Is this good? Or do you see a big reason why I should make the column Integer instead

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of data it is and what you need to do with it.  If it's a number that you never need to do any math operations on (like an ID or a ZIP code), then it should be fine to store it as text.  Obviously if you're going to be counting on SQL aggregate functions to process the data in your database you're going to want to store numbers as numeric data, not text.  One last consideration is input validation.  If you're storing text from the user straight to the database, you need to be sure it's valid data.  It might be simpler to just validate each input once and convert it to the right type before storing it.